# Excel VBA - Passing a Dynamic Range to a Function

Tags: excel, vba

I created a function in Excel VBA:

```
Function codeList(Criteria As String, LookupRange As Range, ValueRange As Range, delimiter As String)
```

It works great when I pass hard coded ranges to it like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=codelist(RC[2],R2C4:R84C4,R2C3:R84C3,"","")"
```

I would like the rows to be dynamic, so instead of saying C2:C84 or D2:D84 I would like to make the C84 / D84 vary based on the number of columns that have data.

I tried to compute the last row and concatenate the ranges to make them dynamic when I call the function, but I get a compile syntax error :

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=codelist(RC[2],"R2C4:R" & lastrow &"C4", "R2C3:R" & lastrow & "C3"),"","")"
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: I think this fixes the concatenation and gets rid of the extraneous parenthesis: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=codelist(RC[2], R2C4:R" & lastRow & "C4, R2C3:R" & lastRow & "C3,"","")"`

Comment: Thanks BigBen!  This syntax worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to include double quotes inside a string, you have to use two double quotes to escape them.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=codelist(RC[2],R2C4:R" & lastRow & "C4, R2C3:R" & lastRow & "C3,"""")"
```

The four double quotes near the end convert to two double quotes (the empty string your looking for).

This way is longer, but I tend to use offsets in formulas. I find it easier to read than trying to determine where the strings begin and end

```
Const DBLQTE As String = """"""

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=codelist(RC[2]," & _
    Range("D2").Resize(lastRow - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & _
    "," & _
    Range("C2").Resize(lastRow - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & _
    "," & _
    DBLQTE & _
    ")"
```

**Update**

For a comma delimeter

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=codelist(RC[2],R2C4:R" & lastRow & "C4, R2C3:R" & lastRow & "C3,"","")"
```

and

```
Const COMMA As String = ""","""
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=codelist(RC[2]," & _
    Range("D2").Resize(lastRow - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & _
    "," & _
    Range("C2").Resize(lastRow - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & _
    "," & _
    COMMA & _
    ")"
```

Comment: I think OP wanted a comma (delimiter) as the last argument of `codelist`, not an empty string.

Comment: If a comma is indeed the desired output, use `CHAR(44)` and clear out the `"",""`.

Comment: Dick - Thanks for the detailed answer!  This worked great.  I also used the char(44) Jeeped suggested.

Comment: Good catch @BigBen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Qualify the parent worksheet and resize according to the column's populated limit. Resize every associated range that needs to be the same size.

```
Function codeList(Criteria As String, LookupRange As Range, ValueRange As Range, delimiter As String)

    with LookupRange.parent
        set LookupRange = .range(LookupRange.cells(1), .cells(.rows.count, LookupRange.cells(LookupRange.cells.count).column).end(xlup))
        set ValueRange = ValueRange.cells(1).resize(LookupRange.rows.count, LookupRange.columns.count)
    end with

    'all the rest of the code

end function
```

Never use ActiveSheet or ActiveCell in a worksheet's UDF. The originating cell where the formula is in is the [Application.Caller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-caller-property-excel).

Comment: Thanks for the tips!